# What are the IEC standards/certifications to look for in a DSO while making measurements pertaining analog parameters like CMRR, SNR, THD etc

Tags: oscilloscope, test-equipment, production-testing, cmrr, iec

I am in the process of measuring CMRR for our mixed signal system that deals with bio-signal acquisition. I am using DSOX2014A keysight entry-level oscilloscope to make measurement to derive CMRR, SNR and THD. My test-plan is almost ready for it but I am stuck only here, that how can we know whether a test-equipment qualifies to make measurements of such peculiarity. CMRR and SNR are the parameters which are highly considered while pursuing standards and certifications like IEC, CE etc for a Device under test.

I definitely know, what signal I am measuring, what is its range and accordingly the bandwidth of scope required, the least count of different measurements that the scope can offer. Also I am sure about oscilloscope's accuracy. I am asking in terms of certifications that, what IEC certification, certifies a test equipment to make measurements of these type in a laboratory set-up. After a long research conducted on this, I am unable to come to any conclusion. I found IEC 61000-4-16:2015, but that is for the DUT to qualify during mass production, nothing of the sort of test equipment standard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: THD and SNR are usually measured by specialist equipment like https://www.ap.com/ (for audio, or other, specific to other domains); a general purpose scope is pretty hopeless for the job. CMRR can be the same, if you require decent accuracy. But maybe your Keysight has processing built-in for the job though?

Comment: Well there is no internal function to get the value of CMRR at hand. Those are offered by mid-level keysight equipment. Here i will have to derive all the components manually, like common mode gain, Common mode voltage etc. This is just a basic scope. THD and SNR again im measuring using this scope. My input signal is generally 0-20mV in the frequency range 0-100Hz(sinusoidal) The scope can measure micro-volt level signals with good accuracy and are repeatable. and thus i rely on this scope.